# Override Domain-Restricted Content in a View

Tags: 7, views, domain-access

I have a site running [Domain Access](http://drupal.org/project/domain), which is restricting content to the domain it was created on. Using [Domain Views](http://drupal.org/project/domain_views), I've created two types of views:

1. views displaying content for the current domain.
2. views displaying content for all domains.

However, #2 displays as #1 for anyone without the "Administer Content" permission. How can I set this up so anonymous users on one.mysite.com can see linked content on two.mysite.com ?

In addition, when they click links to other domains, I want them to be transfered to the other domain to view the content.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I posted this on the Domain Access issue queue as a support request and got [this helpful answer](http://drupal.org/node/1401862#comment-5461704):

You can only accomplish #2 under three conditions:

1. The content is marked "Send to all affiliates"; or
2. The view is a page marked as a Special Page Request (which disables Domain Access rules); or
3. The view is set to ignore node access control -- this is an advanced Views configuration.

Option 3 can create security issues if you are using other node access modules.

To make the content link to the appropriate domain, use Domain Source, which lets you specify a canonical URL for each node. If you don't use Domain Source, the canonical URL is calculated for you.

Comment: Nice work and round up mtro. But all the conditions made in the issue queue answer to how it could work lead me to the question that it seems to be quite impossible to have 2 almost same views on the same internal path, but domain depending if they show up. Hm, interesting question maybe for another post ...