# domain access display content to ANONYMOUS USER

Tags: 7, nodes, domain-access

I have create basic page that only displays on domain one and not the others which I want. The issue is that the page will only display when the user is log in and I want ANONYMOUS USER to see the content

Under the permissions the View published content has the  ANONYMOUS USER ticked 
but I can't seem to find a way or why the content is not displaying until an authenticated user is logged in

Comment: What Drupal version and what contrib modules that manage permissions do you use? Did you clear all cache? Is maintenance mode off ? Did you check if there are any content-type level or field level permissions set? Did you check content type-level and field-level permissions set for the Anonymous role?

Comment: Ok I have drupal 7

Comment: Thanks for the reply I have drupal 7 yes I did clear the cache. Domain Access 7.x-2.18, Domain Content Types, The site is not in maintenance mode. I can't seem to find content type-level and field-level in people/permissions

Comment: Did you check Domain Access rules and whatever is suggested in http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/19273/override-domain-restricted-content-in-a-view? What happens when you set view to ignore node access control (in advanced View configuration)?

Answer (score 5):

Under admin/structure/domain/roles you have to checkbox guest -> all domains.